# Scanner/Radio/Transmission Fans out there?

Tags: ambience, experimental, music, radio-frequency

I recently found this amazing site that mixes a live feed of carefully selected ambient music tracks from soundcloud with police scanner chatter from several cities (only one city at a time) that sounds so unbelieveably lush and just utterly and amazingly beautiful. It's almost creepy how well this actually works together.

It came to my attention since one of my recent ambient/cinematic pieces was chosen to be one of the featured songs and I got over 1000 plays on soundcloud within 3 days and I was wondering why/how.

Here's the site:

http://youarelistening.to

You can choose the city transmission that you want to feed your mix. LA, NY, Chicago, Montreal.

I also find that it sounds really interesting if you open multiple tabs of the same location and stop the music (soundcloud player) on any/all the duplicates except the original, thus giving you multiple copies of the scanner feed (with a slight time delay on each) on top of the one single ambient song.

I even took a bit of time to record some of the chatter with variable multitudes of instances because some of the sounds just sounded so interesting and potentially useful.

I know when my daughter was finally old enough I kept the "baby monitors" we used to listen in on her when she was sleeping just in-case I ever possibly needed them for some "worldizing" or any signal processing that they might be appropriate for. I've actually been able to use them a few times to great results.

I've also heard some great stories of people actually having things transmitted through radio transmissions (like Walter Murch for THX 1138) so they can re-record it for the "worldized" and unpredictable results.

Hopefully some of you have some interesting stories about related things. Please share.

Answer (score 1):

Nice! Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

that really is beautiful.  nice find!

Answer (score 0):

Really nice. Thanks.

Seems they've increased the number of cities available too. I wonder if the police radio operators know they're being listened to in this way and what they think of it?

On the radio worldizing tip, these days you can buy weak FM transmitters designed for use with your Ipod in the car - [this sort of thing](http://www.techradar.com/news/audio/portable-audio/best-fm-transmitter-for-iphone-ipod-5-on-test-1035323). Useful.